# accessing dynamic class name ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class_name = "TestClass"
Object.const_set class_name,Class.new{
    include MOduleX
}

#module_x.rb
module ModuleX
    def ModuleX.included (klass)
         p klass.name #=> nil
    end
end
```

I need to access the name of the class ("TestClass" in this case) inside the module, how can I do it?

Comment: MOduleX needs to be Modulex. Will delete this comment...

Comment: This is normally written `self.included(klass)`. That way, if you rename the module you don't need to remember to change this statement also.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, `const_set` is occuring after `Class.new`. At the point where `ModuleX` is included (`MOduleX` is, I assume, a typo), the class is well and truly nameless.

Not to even mention that a constant can't be called `test`, as Ruby grammar mandates that constants must start with a capital letter.

However, if your module must know the class name at inclusion time, it's probably doing something wrong. I suggest rethinking and refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

@Amadan has explained why that won't work, but you can get it if you are able to write it like this:

```
class_name = "Test"

module ModuleX
  def self.included(klass)
    puts "klass = #{klass}"
  end
end

Object.const_set class_name, Class.new do  
end.include ModuleX
  #=> "klass = Test"
```